# Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library

Tags: excel, vba

So I am writing an Excel VBA Macro that needs the "Microsoft Outlook 16 Library" to be activated. When I try to activate it and click on "OK", the following message shows up:

"Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library."

The libraries that I have active on the Excel VBA are:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 16 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Work 16 Object Library

I don't see where the conflict with the "Microsoft Outlook 16 Object Library" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, probably, like the error says, have a module, a procedure or public variable with the name "Outlook".

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and write "Outlook". Check the radio button 'Current Project' and press 'Find Next' and check step by step where such a named object exists. Rename it and after that you will be able to set the reference you need.